# What technique does the torrent client use to split files into packet sized chunks to send them?

Tags: file

I'm working on a peer to peer file sharing program and in order to send large files using UDP packets I need to split them into smaller pieces and then rebuild them. One idea is to use c#'s Stream/FileStream class to split the file and the rebuild it when it gets to its destination. However, I wonder how torrent does this. Thanks.